# log4perl run from within another package not firing messages sent through email

Tags: perl, log4perl

I'm seeing behavior that I can't explain when using log4perl to send a message by email.

So the following test script works just fine and an email is sent without problems:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
use Log::Dispatch;

my $appender_email = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP",
    threshold => "INFO",
    to => 'myemail@mail.com',
    subject => 'Perl script message'
);

my $email_logger = get_logger();
$email_logger->level($INFO);
$email_logger->add_appender($appender_email);

$email_logger->info('hi');
```

The `Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP` is a module I wrote to send emails using the ssmtp command.

The weirdness begins when this same exact code is moved to another package in another file in the same directory as my original script. When I do that and use that package from within my original script, no email gets sent and there are no errors thrown.

However, if I change:

`Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP`

to

`Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen`

It prints out "hi" to the screen just fine when I run my script.

So if log4perl works when sending the message to the screen, why doesn't it work when trying to send an email? And why does the same code fire an email from within the original script and not from a package? Again, there are no errors getting thrown or any kind of indication that something went wrong. And I have verified that my module gets loaded with print statements. So my module's code is definitely getting loaded but the email is still not firing.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code when it's *not* working per request in comments.

`maillog.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
BEGIN { unshift @INC, "/home/steve/perl/perl-lib" }
use strict;
use warnings;
use Testy;

print 'start' . "\n";
```

Here is the `Testy.pm` package:

```
package Testy;
BEGIN { unshift @INC, "/home/steve/perl/perl-lib" }
use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
use Log::Dispatch;

print 'end' . "\n";
my $appender_email = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP",
    #"Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen",
    threshold => "INFO",
    to => 'myemail@mail.com',
    subject => 'Perl script message'
);

my $email_logger = get_logger();
$email_logger->level($INFO);
$email_logger->add_appender($appender_email);

$email_logger->info('hi');

1;
```

And here is my `SSMTP` module located in `/home/steve/perl/perl-lib/Log/Dispatch/Email/SSMTP`:

```
package Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Dispatch::Email;
use Data::Dumper;

use base qw( Log::Dispatch::Email );
print "hi, i'm here!\n";

sub send_email {
  my $self = shift;
  my %p = @_; 
  my $to = escape ( join ',', @{$self->{to}} );
  my $subject = $self->{subject};
  my $message = $p{message};
  $message =~ s/'/'\\''/g;
  print $to . "\n";
  print $subject . "\n";
  print $message . "\n";
  print "I'm working!";

  system("echo 'To: $to\nFrom: \'Me\' <myemail\@gmail.com>\nSubject:$subject\n\n$message' | /usr/sbin/ssmtp $to");
}

sub escape {
  my $address = shift;
  $address =~ s/@/\\@/g;
  return $address;
}

1;
```

When I run `./maillog.pl` no email is sent when using the code in the `Testy` package (the same code works when in `maillog.pl` file. However, if I uncomment `Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP` and replace with `Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen` it works.

**UPDATE #2**
If I change `Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen` to `Log::Dispatch::Screen` it works as well. So maybe come kind of bug in `Log::Dispatch::Email`?

Comment: Can you produce an example that mirrors what your code looks like when you don't receive an email? Any advice people can give is limited because they can't see the "real" code.

Comment: `Log::Dispatch` and `Log::Log4Perl` are different logging solutions; you seem to have written your email appender for `Log::Dispatch` but use it in `Log::Log4Perl`..?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, ok I added all the relevant code.

Comment: @Kenney, but the same code works just fine when run directly from within maillog.pl file (see my added code above)

Comment: Strange. When I diff your first snippet with `Testy.pm` the only real difference is the email address (`myemail@email.com` vs `s@dondley....`) - you probably changed it for posting here, so that's probably not it?

Comment: @kenney, found the problem. See below.

Comment: Ah, thanks for letting me know. According to the doc `Log::Dispatch::EMail` will [flush when it is destroyed](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Log-Dispatch/lib/Log/Dispatch/Email.pm#$email-%3EDESTROY). Maybe the destructor isn't called when it is loaded via a module? Buffering is handy to only get one mail per script run, though; you could consider another workaround like `END { $appender_email->flush() }`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem with some help from the FAQ at  [click here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl-1.30/lib/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.pm#How_can_I_configure_Log::Log4perl_to_send_me_email_if_something_happens)

Apparently, there is some buffering going on so emails do not get sent out immediately until some threshold for the number of messages generated is reached. Though it's still a mystery to me as to why emails are sent immediately when the code is in the `main` package.

So here is the code that works with the `buffered` property set to 0:

```
my $appender_email = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Dispatch::Email::SSMTP",
    threshold => "INFO",
    to => 'me@mymail.com',
    buffered => 0,
    subject => 'Perl script message'
);
```